# Area 51 Stats for 2012

Tags: discussion, statistics

Here are the stats for Area 51 for December 2012...

These were pulled from the web archive

## **December 2012:**

[image: Dec 2012 Visits per day]

## **May 2012:**

[image: May 2012 Visits per day]

## **January 2012 (a year ago):**

[image: January 2012 Visits per day]

**Source:**

- [Jan 2012 Area 51 Web Archive](http://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120113052119/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management)
- [May 2012 Area 51 Web Archive](http://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120527034339/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management)
- Dec 2012 Area 51 Web Archive - Pulled in real-time on December 10th.