# Our two year anniversary is coming up, how should we celebrate?

Tags: discussion

February 7, 2013 marks our second anniversary since day 1 of the private beta.  Should we celebrate this event somehow? If so, how?

Comment: Um...award 10,000 points to all active participants as party gifts? :)

Comment: We'll double everyone's points, then divide them in half, and repeat the process until everyone is above 10,000. ;D Sorry, bad joke.

Answer (score 3):

PMI grants CPE/PDU for blogging on their site.  I wonder who we'd need to contact to arrange credit for answering questions here.

Comment: Good idea. Maybe there's a point of contact for Internet marketing?  Mark Phillips might know the answer to that as I think he might be an active PMI member.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should summarize the achievements of this website, such as:

1. Membership growth
2. Reputation growth
3. # of questions asked vs # of accepted answers
4. Range of pm topics covered
5. Range of pm tools covered

One possibility is to blog about this and share it on social media as well so that more people may have a chance to discover the site and participate.

I volunteer to write up the first draft, although I don't have a clue how to get the data for 1 to 3 yet.

Comment: Hi Ashok, this is a great suggestion. Many of these stats are available in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management).  Also, you can see snapshots of where we were a year ago in [this PMSE Meta post](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/555/34).

Answer (score 2):

### Second Anniversary Blog – Draft

As promised, I have written a draft of the second Anniversary Blog. I am new around here. I suggest that one of the senior members should publish this blog. Please feel free to edit it, as needed.

---

**Excellent Q&A Site; Got to Reach More Project Management Practitioners**

February 7, 2013 marks the  second anniversary of [The Project Management Q&A Site on Stack Exchange (PMSE)](https://pm.stackexchange.com/). It is [rated “Excellent” even by the very demanding standards of Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management).

- Questions answered: 90% answered is healthy. We are at 100% answered, which is excellent.
- Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. Stack Exchange recommends a minimum number of users with certain reputation levels. We currently exceed all these, which is excellent. Minimum of 150 users with a reputation score of 200+; we are currently at 214 users. Minimum of 10 users with a reputation score of 2,000+; we are currently at 17 users. Minimum of 5 users with a reputation score of 3,000+; we are currently at 12 users.
- Answers per question: 2.5 answers per question is good. We are at 4, which is excellent.
- Visits per day: 1,500 visits per day is good. We are at 1849, which is excellent.

A variety of questions get answered here:

- On a range of project management processes: From traditional project management to CMMI to Earned Value Management (EVM) as well as from Waterfall to RUP to Agile/Scrum/Kanban/Extreme Programming (XP).
- In a range of industries:  Construction, software development, aerospace, defense and others.
- About a range of tools and solutions: Desktop and web-based Project Management tools such as MS Project/Project Server, Agile/Scrum tools such as Rally and other commercial tools as well as open source tools such as Redmine and Trac.

Also we have [tripled the site traffic over the last one year](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/area-51-stats-for-2012) from just an okay level of about 600 visits per day to an excellent level of about 1800 visits per day. Do we rest on our laurels saying we have done a great job?

To get a broader understanding of what percentage of PM users we are reaching, let us look at some stats. We have currently about 5000 users. The [2011 Annual Report of the Project Management Institute (PMI)](http://www.pmi.org/About-Us/About-Us-Annual-Report.aspx) reports “more than 600,000 PMI members and credential holders in more than 184 countries”. Some of the open source project management tools have been downloaded a few million times. Among commercial tools, [Microsoft claims to have 20 million users for Project and Project Server](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/project-portfolio-management-competency.aspx). This is not counting other project management tools and solutions.

So, it is clear that we have just scratched the surface of the user base. Here is a great Q&A site where you pop the question that is blocking you from managing your project better and you are guaranteed to get a satisfactory resolution. But the vast majority of project management professionals as well as casual users seem to be totally unaware of that.

Let us spread the word. On this second anniversary we are asking everyone’s help to get the message out. Please share the link to this blog with your professional contacts. Send an email, put it on your web site or curate it. Share it on FaceBook, Twitter, LinkedIn and other social media sites. And they will thank you when their next Project Management problem gets resolved or, even better, when they are able to help resolve another user’s problem.

Comment: Hi Ashok, thanks for putting this together. If you have a blog, you could publish this yourself. Otherwise, maybe one of our PMSE users could publish you as a guest author on their blog?  One suggestion, in the 2nd to last paragraph, I suggest focusing on the fact that this is *not* a forum but instead is a Q&A site. Sometimes this does trip people up a bit when they first visit. :)

Comment: I have changed the Forum to Q&A site. I don't have a blog. I am open to going the guest blog route.

Comment: Hi @jmort253, Tomorrow being Feb 7, let me know whether I should be publishing the blog. If so, appreciate any guidance you can provide in advance for the guest blog.

Comment: Hi Ashok, in terms of publishing this post, it's all up to you and whomever would be interested in posting this to a blog they're affiliated with. I'll drop a link to this in our [chat] to see if anyone else bites. Good luck, and thank you for putting this together! :)

Comment: I published the blog on my hobby site here: http://smb-soft.com/blog

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for putting this together. :)

Comment: Great post, Ashok! Thanks for putting it together.

Comment: @MarkPhillips - Hi Mark! :) Can you take a look at this?  http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/a/582/34